# Laravel Models and displaying them on view together

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

For a school assignment we have two tables and models players and countries 
I know its either my models or my controller (I've had this problem before but in another assignment their was only one country so i just looped through a country variable and used arrays instead but this wont work for multiple countries)

When I try to display in the view i get "Trying to get property of non-object 'name' on the {{$player->country->name}} and this is the way the teacher has explicitly said we are to display it.


Currently before anything else id like to display all my players and their country names 
**Models**

```
class Country extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'countries';
    protected $fillable=['name','flag'];
    public function player(){
        return $this->hasMany(Player::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Player extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable =['name','age','role','batting','bowling','image','odiRuns','countries_id'];
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }
}
```

**Tables**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('flag');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('players', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('age');
            $table->string('role');
            $table->string('batting');
            $table->string('bowling');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('odiRuns');
            $table->integer('countries_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('countries_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
            $table->timestamps();
         });
    }
```

**Controller**

```
use App\Player;
use App\Country;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PlayerController extends Controller
{
 public function index()
    {
        //
        $players=Player::all();

        return view('index',compact('players'));
    }
```

**View**

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')

    @foreach ($players as $player )
    {{$player->name}}
    {{$player->age}}
    {{$player->role}}
    {{$player->batting}}
    {{$player->bowling}}
    {{$player->odiRuns}}
    {{$player->country->name}}
    @endforeach
    @endsection
```

**Edit**
players all have country id's relating to the countries table 
**Tables**
[players table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppaZI.png)

[countries table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI73C.png)

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. The error suggests that some `player` does not have a `country`. Just check your database records.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your missing foreign key in relation. When you are defining a relationship, if you explicitly don't tell which foreign key to use for the relationship, Laravel looks for a foreign key like `relationname_primarykeyoftheparenttable`. In your case its `country_id` but in your players table the column name is `countries_id`. So relationship is not building and you are getting error. Change the column name or tell the relationship which foreign key to use to build the relationship.

```
class Player extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =['name','age','role','batting','bowling','image','odiRuns','countries_id'];

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class,'countries_id');
    }
}
```

[Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: Thank you i did this a second ago not realizing this and how laravel looks for foreign keys. Thank you so much for the insight behind this too